# Importing a new cassandra related POM dependency in project resulting in run time errors

Tags: java, database, maven, cassandra

I'm getting the following errors :

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Failed to load provider from META-INF/services
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:115)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:757)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hom.CassandraPersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.locator.ProviderLocator.loadClass(ProviderLocator.java:195)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.locator.ProviderLocator.locateServiceClasses(ProviderLocator.java:524)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.locator.ProviderLocator.getServices(ProviderLocator.java:315)
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:108)
    ... 101 more
```

I have imported a pom dependeny in my project, the new pom dependeny inturn has some cassandra related dependeny shown below :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The cassandra project works good in stand alone. Can someone help me with this

Comment: what is your cassandra version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is complaining `ClassNotFoundException:me.prettyprint.hom.CassandraPersistenceProvider` which belongs to Cassandra hector client.

I am guessing your project was using `hector core` which is no longer active [hector client github page](https://github.com/hector-client/hector).  You have to migrate all dependencies to datastax's cassandra drivers and remove all hector-client related dependencies. check it [here](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/)

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly after including the dependency :)